# Arduino- Duty Cycle Changing When Frequency Is Increasing

Tags: arduino, pwm, frequency, button

I’m currently trying to increase the frequency from a pin from an Arduino using PWM. I’m using the Timer1 library as it has functions to output signals.

I connected a push button to my Arduino and this is meant to increase the **frequency** of the pin once **pressed** . But every time the button is pressed, the duty cycle is also changed. Also the frequency changes multiple when the button is pressed. I think that has something to do with the *lastButtonState* logic.
I was wondering if there’s anything that can implemented in my code that can increase the frequency but keep the duty cycle the same.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

int buttonState = 0;
int lastButtonState = 0;
int period = 1000;
int sig_out = 9;
int sig_out2 = 10;
int button =2;

void setup() {

  pinMode(button,INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(sig_out, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(sig_out2, OUTPUT);
  Timer1.initialize(1000);
  Timer1.pwm(sig_out,507,period);
  Serial.print(period);
  //Timer1.pwm(sig_out2,456,900);
}
void loop(){
    buttonState = digitalRead(button);
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState){
     lastButtonState = buttonState;
     if (buttonState == 1){
      period -= 10;
      Timer1.setPeriod(period);  
     }
  }
}
```

[image: Schematic]

Comment: I don't see any debounce for the switch. This could be happening because of that. Try using [debounce](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce) and see if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the `Timer1.pwm()` function call you will see that you are providing two timing parameters: the duty factor and the period. Both of these are specified as an integer number of clock cycles...the duty factor **is not** given as a percentage of the period.

So, when you change the period the output pin stays high for the same number of clock cycles that you specified in `Timer1.pwm()`, which effectively changes the duty factor. If you want to keep the duty factor constant then you need to call `Timer1.pwm` every time you change the period and give it a newly calculated value for the second parameter.

Comment: I added the Timer1.pwm() below the Timer1.setPeriod(period); and the duty cycle stays at 50%.